# Two friends have $2$ natural written on their forehead. One is $2$ times the other + $1$. They can raise their hands.

Tags: logic, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, puzzle, game-theory

### The problem:

Two friends have $2$ natural written on their forehead. One of them is $2$ times the other + $1$. Let's call them $X$ and $2X + 1$. They have to come up with a strategy to guess their own number, and they can raise their hand or not (communicate $1$ bit of information to each other).

So for example if you see $23$ on your friends forehead, you have to decide by only communicating $1$ bit of information whether or not you have $11$ or $47$ on your forehead.

[image: Do I have 11 or 47 on my forehead?]

### My attempt:

(Let's call the number each player sees on their friend's forehead $S$.)

**Step** $1$. If the number you see is even, immediately say "$2S+1$ is on my forehead!"

(Obviously $2X+1$ cannot be even, so we're good so far.)

**Step** $2$. If the number you see is of the form $4n+1$, say "$2S + 1$ is on my forehead!"

(This works too, since if $2X+1=4n+1 \ \rightarrow\ X=2n$, which was already covered in Step $1$. This means that the seen $S = 4n+1 \ne 2X+1$, instead $S = 4n+1=X$, so we our number must be $2X+1$.)

This is where it becomes problamatic, since:

- If $X=4n+3 \ \rightarrow\ 2X+1=8n+7 \stackrel{also}{=} 4\hat{n}+3 \quad (\hat{n} = 2n+1)$
- Not only that, but if $X=8n+7 \ \rightarrow\ 2X+1=16n+15 \stackrel{also}{=} 8\hat{n}+7 \quad (\hat{n} = 2n+1)$

I have also tried divisibility by $3$, $5$ and $6$, but none of those lead to a solution, for example:

- If $X=3n \ \rightarrow\ 2X+1 \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod}\ 3)$ and $X=3n+1 \ \rightarrow\ 2X+1 \equiv 0 \ (\text{mod}\ 3)$, which is all good, if $S=3n$ or $S=3n+1$, you can determine what your number is, ...
- But if $X=3n+2 \ \rightarrow\ 2X+1=6n+5=3\hat{n}+2 \quad (\hat{n} = 2n+1)$, so raising their hand when $S=3n+2$ doesn't work either.

I don't think I'm far from the solution, but i just can't figure it out, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function $X\mapsto 2X+1$ partitions the positive integers into chains, as below. Each chain begins with either an even number, or one, and every number $X$ is joined by an arrow to $2X+1$. It is common knowledge to the two players which chain they are in. Furthermore, all the chains have the same structure. Therefore, we will assume without loss of generality the players are in the indicated chain.

\begin{align}
&\boxed{1\to 3\to 7\to 15\to 31\to \dots}
\\
&2\to 5\to 11\to 23\to47\to \dots
\\
&4\to 9\to 19\to 39 \to 79\to \dots
\\
&6\to 13\to 27\to 55\to 111\to \dots
\\
&8\to 17\to 35\to 71\to 142\to \dots
\\
&\hspace{3cm}\vdots
\end{align}
Color the elements of the chain alternately black and red in blocks of two, as shown. Each player communicates the color they see to the other player using their hand raise. This allows each player to deduce their number. For example, if you had $15$ and your friend had $31$, then you would be unsure whether your number was $15$ or $63$. But once your friend says that your number is red, you know your number is $15$. 
$$
1\to 3\to \color{red}{7}\to \color{red}{15}\to 31\to 63\to \color{red}{127}\to \color{red}{255}\to 511\to  \dots
$$
The color can be described explicitly. The reverse function of $X\mapsto 2X+1$ is $X\mapsto (X-1)/2$, which is defined as long as $X$ is odd and greater than $1$. If you apply the reverse map over and over to the number you see, then you will eventually end up with an even number (or one). If it takes $n$ steps to do this, then you should raise your hand if $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ is even.

Comment: Mike, I found this answer of yours to be really amazing and just cannot figure out how you came up with it, especially the chain part . Firstly, how did you realise that it needs to be thought of in terms of chains ? Secondly, how did you realise that the numbers needed to be colored in blocks of 2 ? Was all this through trial and error or was there some intuition that got you to come up with this method ? Just trying to get to know of your thinking process.

Comment: Hermant, the chains are easy. Just think, "If I see 7 (for example), what could I have?" Answer: 3 or 15. "If my opponent sees 3 or 15, what could they have in their mind?" Answer: 1 or 7 or 15. If you keep extending that reasoning, the chain 1 -> 3 -> 7 -> 15 -> ... naturally appears. If you apply the same logic with other numbers, you see the pattern emerge. It definitely helps to think of the numbers in binary, and how $2X+1$ acts on binary representations, to understand why the chains are disjoint.

Comment: The coloring just comes from thinking, "Both players are confused between two numbers in the chain which are two places apart, for example if I see 7, I am confused between 3 and 15. Therefore, we need a signal that can tell apart adjacent numbers in the list of every other number in the chain, 3 -> 15 -> 63 -> ... A good way to distinguish adjacent numbers is an alternating coloring. You then just so happen to get the repeating blocks of two when you interleave two alternating colorings."